# How to add up the steering forces to achieve flocking behavior

Tags: java, boids

I am trying to implement a flocking boids program based on Cornrad Prkers' algorithm. I seem to be having problems with summing up all the forces (alignment, cohesion and separation). I keep getting a weird behavior.

The alignment part of the algorithm is responsible for velocity matching.

```
public Point alignment(Boids boid){

    double xVelocity = 0;
    double yVelocity = 0;

    ArrayList<Boids> neighborhood = new ArrayList<Boids>();
    neighborhood = neighborHood(boid, Boids.DetectionRange);
    if(neighborhood.size() > 1){

        for(int i = 0; i < neighborhood.size(); i++){
                Boids otherBoid = neighborhood.get(i);
                if(boid != otherBoid){
                    xVelocity += otherBoid.velocity.x;
                    yVelocity += otherBoid.velocity.y;
                }
        }
        xVelocity /= neighborhood.size();
        yVelocity /= neighborhood.size();
    }
    else{
        return new Point(0, 0);
    }
    return new Point((int)xVelocity, (int)yVelocity);
}
```

the separation is responsible for collsion avoidance

```
public Point sepration(Boids boid){
    double xPosition = boid.location.x;
    double yPosition = boid.location.y;
    double xDistance = 0;
    double yDistance = 0;
    ArrayList<Boids> neighborhood = new ArrayList<Boids>();
    neighborhood = neighborHood(boid, Boids.SeperationRange);
    if (neighborhood.size() > 1){
    for(int i = 0; i < neighborhood.size(); i++){
        Boids otherBoid = this.get(i);
        if(boid != otherBoid){
            xDistance = (int) (boid.location.x - otherBoid.location.x);
            yDistance = (int) (boid.location.y - otherBoid.location.y);

            if(boid.checkCollision(otherBoid.getLocation())){
                if(xDistance > 0 && xDistance < Boids.SeperationRange){
                    xPosition -= xDistance;
                }                   
                if(yDistance > 0 && yDistance <  Boids.SeperationRange){
                    yPosition -= yDistance;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }else{
        return new Point(0,0);
    }
    xPosition /= neighborhood.size();
    yPosition /= neighborhood.size();

    return new Point((int)xPosition, (int)yPosition);
}
```

the cohesion is responsible for the flocking behavior, boids are attracted to each other as long as they are within their detection range.

```
public Point cohesion(Boids boid){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    ArrayList<Boids> neighborhood = new ArrayList<Boids>();
    neighborhood = neighborHood(boid, Boids.DetectionRange);
    if (neighborhood.size() > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < neighborhood.size(); i++){
        Boids otherBoid = neighborhood.get(i);
            if(boid != otherBoid){
                x += otherBoid.location.x;
                y += otherBoid.location.y;
            }
            x /= neighborhood.size();
            y /= neighborhood.size();
        }
    }else{
        return new Point(0 , 0); // empty vector
    }
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Each of the steering behavior returns a vector (Point in Java), which I then normalize and then apply a weighted force of the unit vector, to move it one unit to its target point.

Comment: The points seem to be `int` based. This robs you of the precision you get from the `double` calculations. You might want to keep things an `double` as long as possible.

Comment: I figured that out, but unfortunately the x and y coordinates of graphics object in java are int precision, so even if the calculations are double the final value to be added to the x-y position has to be an int

Comment: You should do all your calculations in the needed precision. For display purpose you can either cast them to int (loosing everything behing the comma) or round them to the nearest int `(int forDisplay = (int)(Math.round(original)))`